# Get more detail about a view in View Hierarchy object inspector

Tags: swift, xcode, class, object, view

I'm trying to debug an app where some cells in a table view are getting highlighted depending on the state of one of their member variables.

The highlighting is done in the setSelected function, which is called every time the user scrolls through the table.

The issue is that some cells seem to have their member variables set to either nil or some other values, which should not be the case (especially blank cells which are being used as spacer (yes, bad practice)).

I realised there is a View Hierarchy debugger in XCode, and I was wondering if I could just 'focus' on a specific view to see what its class object was holding as value. The object inspector is not really detailed enough to see what the member variables are set to.

What I am asking might actually not be doable at all, but I just haven't found any posts about this specifically anywhere.

Comment: You want to print out variables of your UI elements? You can use the view hierarchy debugger in Xcode, select the view you're interested in, get the memory address from the inspector and then use Xcode's console to print variables of that UI object. E.g. po [(UIView *)0x12345678 myVariable]